# integrate 3 body system in python

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

This is more mathemathical question.

We have 3 body system, with known initial parametrs like positions, masses, velocityes. This make system like 
[image]

i and j  = 1,2,3  
So question is how to deal with this, to feed this system to **scipy odeint** ?

**UPDATE**
 I wrote code

```
from scipy import linspace
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def rf(i, j, r):
    x1, y1, z1 = r[0]
    x2, y2, z2 = r[1]
    x3, y3, z3 = r[2]
    r12 = ((x1-x2)**2+(y1-y2)**2+(z1-z2)**2)**2
    r13 = ((x1-x3)**2+(y1-y3)**2+(z1-z3)**2)**2
    r23 = ((x2-x3)**2+(y2-y3)**2+(z2-z3)**2)**2
    if i == 1:
        if j == 2:
            r = r12
        elif j == 3:
            r = r13
    if i == 2:
        if j == 1:
            r = r12
        elif j == 3:
            r = r23
    if i == 3:
        if j == 1:
            r = r13
        elif j == 2:
            r = r23
    return r


def dotf(r, t0):
    x1, y1, z1 = r[0]
    x2, y2, z2 = r[1]
    x3, y3, z3 = r[2]
    x = [x1, x2, x3]
    y = [y1, y2, y3]
    z = [z1, z2, z3]

    k2 = 6.67e-11
    m = [2e6, 2.2e7, 0.1e3]

    for i in range(1, 3, 1):
        xs, ys, zs = 0, 0, 0
        for j in range(1, 3, 1):
            if i != j:
                r = rf(i, j, r)
                xs = xs + m[j]*(x[i]-x[j])/r
                ys = ys + m[j]*(y[i]-y[j])/r
                zs = zs + m[j]*(z[i]-z[j])/r
        x[i] = -1 * k2 * xs
        y[i] = -1 * k2 * ys
        z[i] = -1 * k2 * zs
    return [[x1,y1,z1], [x2,y2,z2], [x3,y3,z3]]


t = linspace(0, 50, 1e4)
r1 = [1, 2, 1]
r2 = [0.5, 0.1, 3]
r3 = [0.6, 1, 1.5]
r = [r1, r2, r3] 

u = odeint(dotf, r, t)
```

and get output error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "3b.py", line 73, in <module>
    u = odeint(dotf, r, t)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/odepack.py", line 148, in odeint
    ixpr, mxstep, mxhnil, mxordn, mxords)
ValueError: object too deep for desired array
```

Comment: Have you attempted coding this yet? Can you show some code for this?

Comment: StackOverflow is not a code-writing service.  Please refer to http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve.

Comment: I wrote code but get error, and dont know if I do it correct because I don't have some example to confirm that computation is good

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've corrected two obvious bugs in your code; it runs, but I'm not
sure it's correct.  Code at the end.

The first bug is that `odeint` wants to deal in vectors for state and
state derivative.  By vector I mean rank-1 arrays; you were submitting
a matrix (rank-2 array) as your initial condition.  I've changed the
`r` assignment, possibly confusingly, as `r = r1 + r2 + r3` - the `+`
operator on lists is concatenation, though on numpy arrays it is
element-wise addition.

This change meant I had to change the assignment to `x1`, etc., in
`dotf` and `rf`.  I also change the return from `dotf` to be a vector.

The second bug is that you used `r` to mean two different things:
first, the system state vector, and second the return from `rf`.  I
changed the second one to be `rr`.

The solution appears to be unstable; I don't know if this is
plausible.  I imagine there are other bugs, but you at least have
something that runs now.

My suggestion is starting with something simpler that you know the
solution to, e.g., stable first-order linear system, or a stable
underdamped second-order system, or Lorenz if you want something
chaotic.

See http://docs.scipy.org/doc/ for Scipy documentation, e.g., I used
http://scipy-0.13.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.odeint.html#scipy.integrate.odeint
for `odeint` for Scipy 0.13.0 (which is what comes with my Ubuntu
14.04 system).

```
from scipy import linspace
from scipy.integrate import odeint

def rf(i, j, r):
    x1, y1, z1 = r[:3]
    x2, y2, z2 = r[3:6]
    x3, y3, z3 = r[6:]
    r12 = ((x1-x2)**2+(y1-y2)**2+(z1-z2)**2)**2
    r13 = ((x1-x3)**2+(y1-y3)**2+(z1-z3)**2)**2
    r23 = ((x2-x3)**2+(y2-y3)**2+(z2-z3)**2)**2
    if i == 1:
        if j == 2:
            r = r12
        elif j == 3:
            r = r13
    if i == 2:
        if j == 1:
            r = r12
        elif j == 3:
            r = r23
    if i == 3:
        if j == 1:
            r = r13
        elif j == 2:
            r = r23
    return r


def dotf(r, t0):
    x1, y1, z1 = r[:3]
    x2, y2, z2 = r[3:6]
    x3, y3, z3 = r[6:]
    x = [x1, x2, x3]
    y = [y1, y2, y3]
    z = [z1, z2, z3]

    k2 = 6.67e-11
    m = [2e6, 2.2e7, 0.1e3]

    for i in range(1, 3, 1):
        xs, ys, zs = 0, 0, 0
        for j in range(1, 3, 1):
            if i != j:
                rr = rf(i, j, r)
                xs = xs + m[j]*(x[i]-x[j])/rr
                ys = ys + m[j]*(y[i]-y[j])/rr
                zs = zs + m[j]*(z[i]-z[j])/rr
        x[i] = -1 * k2 * xs
        y[i] = -1 * k2 * ys
        z[i] = -1 * k2 * zs
    return [x1,y1,z1, x2,y2,z2, x3,y3,z3]


t = linspace(0, 50, 1e4)
r1 = [1, 2, 1]
r2 = [0.5, 0.1, 3]
r3 = [0.6, 1, 1.5]
r = r1 + r2 + r3

u = odeint(dotf, r, t)


# uncomment to plot
# from matplotlib import pyplot
#
# pyplot.plot(t,u)
# pyplot.show()
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for showing my mistakes. I read scipy documentation ...but when deals with simple first order equations its all clear and when you start with more complex  - you have some problem. Can't vote for yours answer because low reputation, so if you can - vote please for my first post. It will help me.